# color.plot.phylo in PICANTE, how do you change size (cex) of tips or pass commands to plot.phylo?

Tags: r

I found the `color.plot.phylo` in the package PICANTE which colors the tips of your tree based on a trait. It's a great function, but I haven't been able to pass other commands to the `phylo.plot` function, [as suggested](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/picante/docs/color.plot.phylo).

I'm especially interested in changing the size (`cex`) of the tips and `node.label`. 
Also, is there a way to move the legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function wasn't written in a way that makes it easy to modify those graphical parameters, because certain parameters such as the location of the legend and the size of the text are both hard-coded in the function. If you are somewhat proficient at R you could modify the code of the function to change some of those values. For example, modify the following line in the function:

```
plot.phylo(phylo, cex = 0.8, tip.color = tip.color, main = main, ...)
```

to eliminate the cex value and then you should be able to specify different cex values as an argument to the function. You can find help on writing/modifying functions in R elsewhere on this site and in the R documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I was able to modify the original function and now it does exactly what I wanted.